# Output of Forking in C

Tags: operating-system, fork

Given PID = 4224
Why am I getting output of the following snippet of code as :

x = 10922 y = 0
I am process: 10923
x = 0 y = 2
I am process: 10922
x = 0 y = 2
I am process: 10922
x = 0 y = 0
I am process: 10924

For this code :

```py
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    int pid;
    x=fork();
    if(x==0){
        printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
        pid = getpid();
        printf("I am process: %d\n", pid);
    }
    y  = fork();
    if(y==0){
        printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
        pid = getpid();
        printf("I am process: %d\n", pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: What is the output of the following snippet of code]

Comment: It's hard to understand what it is you are asking exactly. What don't you understand? What do you need help with?

Comment: I need help with the  output of the code?

Comment: Post the code, not a picture of it.   Nobody wants to retype it in order to run it for you....

Comment: @Daniel Right. What help do you need though? If you just want to know the output of the code, type it in and run it. If you have a specific question about understanding what the output is and why it's that way, what's that question?

Comment: I just want the output of running this

Comment: and the reason why it is that output

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    int pid;
    x=fork();
    if(x==0){
        printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
        pid = getpid();
        printf("I am process: %d\n", pid);
    }
    y  = fork();
    if(y==0){
        printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
        pid = getpid();
        printf("I am process: %d\n", pid);
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: x = 0 y = 2
x = 15741 y = 0
I am process: 15742
I am process: 15741
x = 0 y = 0
I am process: 15743

Comment: This above output comes when running the code but since main process pid = 4224 how to include it in the code to run it and why is the above correct answer ?

Comment: No - edit your code, and it's output, into the question itself. If you want help with homework, you should do some...homework.  SO contributors should not need to disentangle code dumped into comments.

Comment: I edit the question the output comes out to be but idk why x = 10922 y = 0
I am process: 10923
x = 0 y = 2
I am process: 10922
x = 0 y = 2
I am process: 10922
x = 0 y = 0
I am process: 10924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with this, the output of your program:

```
x = 0 y = 2     
I am process: 330161
x = 330161 y = 0
I am process: 330162
x = 0 y = 0
I am process: 330163
```

Notice that the order is a bit different from yours.   That is because which process runs first is environment dependent. So, lets fix your program up a bit to be more lucid:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 2;
    int pid;
    x=fork();
    if(x==0){
        pid = getpid();
        printf("1:x = %d y = %d I am process %d\n", x, y, pid);
    }
    fflush(NULL);
    y  = fork();
    if(y==0){
        pid = getpid();
        printf("2:x = %d y = %d I am process %d\n", x, y, pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By placing the printfs together with a single newline, we can rest assured that each statement belongs to one process, they are not interleaved.
By adding an indicator at the beginning of the line `1:, 2:` we know which printf() they came from. The fflush() prevents the child process from inheriting any partially buffered writes from stdio -- not a problem if you are on a terminal, but if you redirect to a file you might find duplicated lines.  So the output on my system looks like:

```
1:x = 0 y = 2 I am process 330214
2:x = 330214 y = 0 I am process 330215
2:x = 0 y = 0 I am process 330216
```

From that, the first child process of the main one is 330214.  The second is 330215; and the grand-child (child of child) is 330216.
I hope that gives you enough to work out your answers.

Don't be afraid to play with these example programs.   It is a good way to learn about the workings of your system.

Comment: but the output comes out to be
x = 10922 y = 0 I am process: 10923 x = 0 y = 2 I am process: 10922 x = 0 y = 2 I am process: 10922 x = 0 y = 0 I am process: 10924

Comment: Did you put the fflush() in?   Your second line is duplicated -- you should never see the same x,y combination.  That is symptomatic of a fork() while there is buffered data in `FILE *` buffers.   Normally, the `\n` in printf would cause a flush, but if you redirect output to an actual file or pipe, that isn't the case.